# parsing using JSoup a website - weatherbug

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have tried several approaches (below) and I have not been able to pull out the temperatures from the hourly forecast of weatherbug: 
http://weather.weatherbug.com/MA/Boston-weather/local-forecast/hourly-forecast.html?zcode=z6286&zip=02108

I am using JAVA / Jsoup.

The temps are listed as: `<span>33&deg; F</span>` within a table.

I suspect my problem is not fully understanding the html.

It appears to be within a table labeled: `<table cellspacing="0" id="hourly">`

Below are several things I have tried with no luck:

It seems like everything I have tried is not able to find or "see" the table.

```
        doc=Jsoup.connect(urlString).get();
        dataread = doc.body().text();
       length = dataread.length();
       System.out.printf("length = %d\n",length);
       System.out.println(dataread);
```

the above was to see if I was at least on track - the data was not in "dataread".

Then I tried printing the results from combinations of:

```
        Elements table = doc.select("table[class=hourly]");
        Elements table = doc.getElementsByTag("boxhdr");
        Elements byclass = doc.getElementsByClass("boxhdr");
        System.out.println(table.size());
        System.out.println(table);
```

I extended my parsing further up the page hoping to get lucky - with the boxhdr label and so forth.

Can you help me extract the temperatures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The table you want to extract the data from has an **id** `hourly`.

```
 Elements table = doc.getElementById("hourly");
```

Moreover, the content of the table is probably generated by Javascript and it's impossible to retrieve it using Jsoup. Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510172/java-html-parser-for-reading-javascript-generated-contents).